# Django - How to make multiple self join tables?

Tags: python, django

I have a table like this:

Its `model`:

```
class RLocation(models.Model):
    id        = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    Parent_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    Name      = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    Geo       = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Sample data:

```
ID      Parent_ID       Name          Geo
1         Null         City A         ABC1                                   City A
12         1          District 1      ABC002                   District 1 in City A
123        12          Ward 1         ABC002003      Ward 1 in District 1 in City A 

25         1          District 5      XYZ004                   District 5 in City A
251        25          Ward 4         XYZ002006      Ward 4 in District 5 in City A
```

Normally, I got the ID of the `ward` (third in the hierarchical). I need to to do query to get the `GEO` of the city (first in the herarchical).

In query (PostgreSQL), I would do something like this :

```
SELECT
l1.Geo
FROM routing.r_location l1  
LEFT JOIN routing.r_location l2 ON l1.ID= l2.Parent_ID       
LEFT JOIN routing.r_location l3 ON l2.ID= l3.Parent_ID       
WHERE l3.ID= '123'
```

Here is my so far code, but I dont really like it:

```
Parent_ID_lv3 = RLocation.objects.filter(ID = 123).values('Parent_ID')
Parent_ID_lv2 = RLocation.objects.filter(ID = Parent_ID_lv3).values('Parent_ID')
Geo_lv1 = RLocation.objects.filter(ID = Parent_ID_lv2).values('Geo')
```

Comment: Why don't you make dedicated `city`, `district` and `ward` fields in your `RLocation` model? That would save you those queries.

Comment: I could not change the database format :(